# Spring MVC is constructing a child object upon form submission when it shouldn't

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm having an issue where a child object is getting constructed even though my form does not specify one should be created. The issue I'm getting is that upon form submission, there are validation field errors with stating that secondary's last and first name is not present.

Ideally, I want secondary to stay null and hence, not validated upon form submission.

The HTML form (snipped for simplicity):

```
<form th:action="@{/quotes/save}" th:object="${quote}">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{primary.lastName}" />
    <input type="text" th:field="*{primary.firstName}" />
</form>
```

The Quote object:

```
@Entity    
public class Quote {
    @ManyToOne
    @Valid
    @NotNull(groups={Quote.ValidationPrimary.class})
    private Person primary;

    @ManyToOne
    @Valid
    private Person secondary;
}
```

The Person object:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;
}
```

The QuoteController:

```
@Controller
public class QuoteController {

    @PostMapping("/quotes/save")
    public String save(@ModelAttribute @Validated({Quote.ValidationPrimary.class}) Quote quote, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        quote.getPrimary(); // this contains a Person object... as expected
        quote.getSecondary(); // this also contains a Person object... which is NOT EXPECTED
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use name when using `th:object` use `th:field` instead. And your controller is a bit different than what I have seen normally. I would recommend changing it for the following code.

**Form**

```
<form th:action="@{/quotes/save}" th:object="${quote}">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{primary.lastName}" />
    <input type="text" th:field="*{primary.firstName}" />
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/quotes/save")
public String save(@ModelAttribute Quote quote, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        quote.getPrimary(); // this contains a Person object... as expected
        quote.getSecondary(); // this also contains a Person object... which is NOT EXPECTED
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was already using th:field but used name just to be clear in my example. I added @ModelAttribute with my @Validated({...}) but secondary is still getting constructed for whatever reason.

Comment: Do they have the same information? Or are they two different Persons?

Comment: primary has the lastName & firstName filled from the form. secondary is constructed but no values set. I should also note that I ran through all of the request parameters after submission and there is nothing that even has "secondary" in them.

Comment: I believe it has to do with the `@Valid` and `@Validate` annotation. Maybe, somewhere you set a default value for your secondary person, which then prevent submitting it as a null value. Can you try, removing the `@Validate` annotation? Also, when you mean no value set, you mean that each String is null?